# How to call ComponentResizer from another class to resize JTextFields?

Tags: java, swing

I'm currently working on a project where I want to be able to resize the JTextField components by dragging the mouse instead of using buttons, and I came across Rob Camick's [Resizing Components Class](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/09/13/resizing-components/) but I'm not sure how to implement/call it in my class, and would appreciate any help, my code is below. Thanks in advance.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.io.*;



import javax.swing.*;

public class Sheet implements Runnable {


LinkedList<Field> fieldList = new LinkedList<Field>();
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Swing Testing...");
public void run() {



    Insets insets = frame.getInsets();


    frame.setLayout(null);





    JButton btn = new JButton("New");
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JButton saveBtn = new JButton("Save");
    JButton loadBtn = new JButton("Load");
    JButton loadTempBtn = new JButton("Load From Template");
    Dimension size = btn.getPreferredSize();

    btn.setBounds(insets.left,insets.top,
             size.width, size.height);
    btn.setLocation(25, 50);

    menuBar.setBounds(insets.left,insets.top,
             size.width, size.height);

    size = saveBtn.getPreferredSize();
    saveBtn.setBounds(insets.left,insets.top,
             size.width, size.height);
    saveBtn.setLocation(500, 30);

    size = loadBtn.getPreferredSize();
    loadBtn.setBounds(insets.left,insets.top,
             size.width, size.height);
    loadBtn.setLocation(550, 30);
    size = loadTempBtn.getPreferredSize();
    loadTempBtn.setBounds(insets.left,insets.top,
             size.width, size.height);
    loadTempBtn.setLocation(600, 30);


    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            btn.setText("You Clicked me!");

            FieldTypeFrame(e);




        }
    });

    saveBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            save(arg0);

        }



    });

    loadBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            load(arg0, frame);

        }



    });

    loadTempBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            loadFromTemp(arg0, frame);

        }
    });


    menuBar.setSize(1000, 25);


    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.addComponentListener(new ComponentListener() {

        @Override
        public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent arg0) {
            menuBar.setSize(arg0.getComponent().getWidth(), 25);

        }

        @Override
        public void componentShown(ComponentEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


    });


    frame.setSize(1000, 1000);
    frame.add(btn);
    frame.add(menuBar);
    frame.add(saveBtn);
    frame.add(loadBtn);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}



public static void main(String args[]) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Sheet());


}

public void save(ActionEvent e) {




    try {
        FileOutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream("page.dat");
        ObjectOutputStream objStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileStream);
        objStream.writeObject(fieldList);
        objStream.close();

        System.out.println("Done");


    }
    catch (Exception error) {

        error.printStackTrace();

    }



}


public void load(ActionEvent e, JFrame frame) {
    int i = 0;

    try {
        LinkedList<Field> list;
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("page.dat");
        ObjectInputStream objInput = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
        list = (LinkedList<Field>)objInput.readObject();
        objInput.close();




            for(int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {

            Field f = list.get(j);
            f.setFrame(frame);
            f.initializeButtons();
            f.add();
        }

        fieldList = list;
        System.out.println("Done");


    }
    catch(Exception error) {


    }



}



public void loadFromTemp(ActionEvent e, JFrame frame) {
    int i = 0;

    try {
        LinkedList<Field> list;
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("Template.dat");
        ObjectInputStream objInput = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
        list = (LinkedList<Field>)objInput.readObject();
        objInput.close();




        for(int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {

            Field f = list.get(j);
            f.setFrame(frame);
            f.initializeButtons();
            f.add();
            f.revalidate();
        }

        fieldList = list;
        System.out.println("Done");


    }
    catch(Exception error) {


    }



}

public void SaveAs(ActionEvent e) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override 
        public void run() {
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
            chooser.showSaveDialog(null);

        }


    });


}

public void FieldTypeFrame(ActionEvent e) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {


            JFrame fieldType = new JFrame("FieldType");
            JButton textBtn = new JButton("Text");
            JButton dataBtn = new JButton("Data");
            JButton checkBtn = new JButton("Check");


            textBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    TextField f = new TextField(frame, 50, 50, 200, 150, "Type Here", "Text Box", "TEXT");
                    fieldList.add(f);       
                    f.add();
                    fieldType.dispose();

                }
            });

            dataBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    DataField f = new DataField(frame, 50, 50, 200, 150, "0", "Data Box", "DATA");
                    fieldList.add(f);       
                    f.add();
                    fieldType.dispose();
                }
            });

            checkBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                    JSlider howMany = new JSlider(0, 25, 0);
                    JButton confirm = new JButton("Confirm");
                    howMany.setMajorTickSpacing(5);
                    howMany.setMinorTickSpacing(1);
                    howMany.setPaintTicks(true);
                    howMany.setPaintLabels(true);

                    confirm.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                            CheckField f = new CheckField(frame, 50, 50, 200, 150, "", "Check Box", "CHECK", howMany.getValue());
                            fieldList.add(f);
                            f.add();
                            fieldType.dispose();
                        }



                    });

                    fieldType.remove(textBtn);
                    fieldType.remove(dataBtn);


                    fieldType.add(howMany);
                    fieldType.add(confirm);
                    fieldType.revalidate();
                    /*
                    Field f = new Field(frame, 50, 50, 200, 150, "Type Here!", "Check Box", "CHECK");
                    fieldList.add(f);       
                    f.add();
                    fieldType.dispose();
                    */
                }
            });


            fieldType.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            fieldType.setSize(300, 300);
            fieldType.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

            fieldType.add(textBtn);
            fieldType.add(dataBtn);
            fieldType.add(checkBtn);





            fieldType.setVisible(true);

        }

    });

}



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ComponentResize` was designed to only work on a panel using a null layout, since you are effectly taking control of the size and location of the component.

So assuming you want to add the component to an empty frame your would do something like:

```
frame.setLayout(null);

JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
textField.setSize( textField.getPreferredSize() );
textField.setLocation(100, 100);
frame.add(textField);

ComponentResizer cr = new ComponentResizer();
cr.registerComponent(textField);
```

When you attempt learn a new class or concept start with something simple. The code you posted is way too involved to learn how to use this class. All you need is a JFrame and a single JTextField to test the class.